# How to setup android test in multiple library modules?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to do some android unit tests in my library modules. However, the "DexIndexOverflowException" occurs when I run my test. In my app module, I have configured mutildex and the app works fine in debug and release variants. And I check from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), I don't need to do other configurations if I use `AndroidJunitRunner` to run my test. So, now I am confused that why it doesn't work in my library module. Are there other correct ways to setup android test in library modules?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this??

Comment: Not yet! I haven't get any solution.